# How to get a sentry 2 "Groups" Record as a Json in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to get a list of groups as a JSON object out of `Sentry::findAllGroups()` method. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using Sentry, because it returns an array of group objects, but you can convert it to json using pure PHP:

```
return json_encode(Sentry::findAllGroups());
```